# Meaning of Go Home

Tags: idioms

I know literal meaning of 'go home'. In the following talk it's vague to me.

> “Let me guarantee you this, based on everything that I know and understand, and the help that [Biden] has already gotten from the Black community ... he can’t ****go home**** without a Black woman being VP,” Waters said. “We’re going to have a Black woman VP.”

Waters insisted that Biden needed a black woman vice president. If so, does 'go home' mean 'go to White House' and not his own real home? I can't find that the phrase means 'succeed' in any dictionary.

Comment: It could just be 'go ahead, go on, move ahead' etc.  Is this usage similar to 'back home' which has a not so close meaning...?

Comment: It could mean _home_ in the sense of the objective, or winning position, in a game.

Comment: It might mean literally going home such as we go home to take rest after hard work of day time. So if Biden doesn't take a black woman as running mate, he cannot go home to take rest and he has to keep worrying.

Comment: It's possible that it's a baseball metaphor - a player doesn't score a point unless he makes it to home (meaning home plate).